# IIS6 how to bind a local site to http form

Tags: website, publishing, iis-6

I have enabled the IIS6 & able to publish my site via hostname:8080 
so any system in my network is opening thru hostname:8080

Now my question is how to give this any http form like I tried binding hostname-internal.com
But its not working.

Pls help me out if you understood the question.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS6 if you go to your website then right click and go to properties check what IP Address it is assigned too and click Advanced. In here it is most likely now assigned to 8080 port this needs to have port 80 listed.

If another site such as the default website is already using port 80 you must remove port 80 from this site first then add this to your new site. Restarting IIS should apply any changes.

Remember of course that you need a DNS A Record to be added for xxxx-xxxxx.com to point to that Server IP in order for a webbrowser to pick up  as a valid site.

Happy to assist more if you get stuck.